# pandas fillna removes timezone when used with value=dict

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I bumped into an unexpected-to-me behaviour in pandas. Here is the code, running python 3.10.8.

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime, timezone

In [2]: import pandas

In [3]: pandas.__version__
Out[3]: '1.4.4'

In [4]: df = pandas.DataFrame(data={"end_date": [datetime(2022, 1, 20, tzinfo=timezone.utc)]})

In [5]: df.end_date.dt.tz
Out[5]: datetime.timezone.utc

In [6]: df.fillna(value={"end_date": datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)}).end_date.dt.tz

In [7]: df.assign(end_date=lambda df: df["end_date"].fillna(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc))).end_date.dt.tz
Out[7]: datetime.timezone.utc
```

As you can see, when using `.fillna(value={...})`, the timezone information is lost even if you do not have any value to fill. But it is kept when no dictionary is used.

Is it expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: cannot reproduce with `pandas.__version__ == '1.5.3'`; both the `fill_na` and the `assign` commands return `datetime.timezone.utc` on my system (Python 3.10.9 on Linux).

Comment: @FObersteiner You are totally right, I just checked on my side too. Thanks for pointing that out.